# Error: (1054, "Unknown column 'q' in 'where clause'")

Tags: mysql, python

Deseo multiplicar el valor de dos columnas bajo la condición de un valor en otra columna.

```
    sql2 = "SELECT cantidad*precio FROM det_factura WHERE idventa='e8'"
    cur.execute(sql2)
    result = cur.fetchone()
    print(result)
```

El problema es en "WHERE idventa", cuando la condición es un número corre bien, pero si es un caracter alfanumérico me sale lo siguiente.

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'e8' in 'where clause'")
```

Pero cuando ejecuto la operación en el mismo Mysql Workbench sí lo hace. Pero desde el Visual Code no.

Comment: Cómo lo estás ejecutando en VS code? El error da a entender que no estás rodeando el valor con comillas simples y lo interpreta como una columna

Answer (score 1):

Deberías usar consultas preparadas en estos casos, no solamente por el asunto de las comillas, sino por el enorme riesgo que podría suponer mandar a ejecutar una consulta en caso de que el dato del `WHERE` pueda ser manipulado por el usuario. El problema es que un usuario mal intencionado podría manipular esos datos y causar graves daños a tu sistema en forma de *inyección SQL*.

Por otra parte, las consultas preparadas son más rápidas, porque ya el manejador, en la primera preparación tranza un plan para esa consulta y si hubiera más consultas de ese tipo irían más rápidas.

Escribir una consulta preparada es relativamente sencillo:

```
# Pasa prepared=True cuando creas la conexión
# Cambiar cnx por el nombre de tu objeto de conexión
cur = cnx.cursor(prepared=True)

stmt = "SELECT cantidad*precio FROM det_factura WHERE idventa = %s"
cur.execute(stmt, ('e8',))
result = cur.fetchone()
print(result)
```

Para más detalles puedes consultar el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorprepared.html).

Comment: Y hay alguna manera de hacer eso con Pandas y sumarlo. Porquecon alfanumericos no me sale. Es extraño.

Answer (score 0):

aveces suele dar error por la comillitas.

te recomiendo utilizar mysql scape que hace un text format ejemplo:

```
sql2 = "SELECT cantidad*precio FROM det_factura WHERE idventa=%s"
cur.execute(sql2, ('e8'))
```

Comment: @Byro Gracias, de esa manera se solucionó